# How do I set up two different groups of dimensions on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make a Minecraft server on [Minehut](https://minehut.com) that has two groups of dimensions (overworld, nether, end). One group will be for survival only, while the other group will allow all game modes. In addition, I want it set up so that ender chests can't sync between those two groups, and your inventory also can't be transferred from those groups. Does anyone have any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: you want separate player data for the dimensions? it would be easier to just have separate servers

Comment: Maybe try the multi world plugin